# Dell Thin Client Screen Issue

Tags: thin-client, multipoint-server-2011

I'll preface this by stating that I don't normally deal with network related systems in the work place.

We recently purchased a handful of thin clients to accommodate bring our internal software to the shop floor of our manufacturing facility. However, the thin clients aren't displaying correctly on the monitor (see image below).

[image: monitor issue]

There is no issue with the camera or quality of the image. This is what it looks like on the monitor with the pink-ish lines running diagonally across the screen.

We ordered 6 of these thin clients, and so far we've tested 2 with the same results on two different brands of monitors (MonoPrice and Dell), which work fine with other terminals w/ same VGA cable.

Specifications:

- [Dell Wyse 1003-E03](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=A8229179) thin clients
- Windows Multipoint Server 2011
- I believe our admin tried installing some drivers from Windows Server 2012 for these clients

Does anyone have a solution to this or tips on how to troubleshoot this issue?

**Update**

So far, we've traced the manufacturer to Magic Control Technology Corp. using the part # (MWS400UL). We got the furthest with downloading a driver directly from them (not Dell's site). However, this hasn't been the solution. Finally, we emailed the manufacturer directly and the y responded saying that there was a bug in their latest driver for Multipoint Server 2011 and *"... will inform [us] once the updated driver version is available."*...

Comment: These new units?

Comment: @Ramhound They're new as-in purchased new from Dell. Idk when they released these units though, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Do these units have HDMI or DVI and/or does your monitors have them?

Comment: These units only have VGA and we've double checked the cables on other systems and the cables are fine.

Comment: soubds like you got a bad batch